# Return map() from a Firebase React Component?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, loops, components, arrow-functions

I want the component **ItemsFromDB** to iterate the content of the objects under the "content" reference in my **Firebase Realtime Database**. But how can I make this component to return my wanted `map()` function, for its inside a snapshot arrow function?

```
function ItemsFromDB () {
 return (
   let ref = firebase.database().ref('content')
   ref.child(name).on('value', function (snapshot) {
    snapshot.map((childSnapshot) => 
    <h2>{childSnapshot.val().name}</h2>
    )
  })
 )
}
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like that

```
function ItemsFromDB () {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('content').child('name');
    const callback = snapshot => (
      setNames(snapshot.map(child => child.val().name))
    );
    ref.on('value', callback);
    
    return () => {
      ref.off('value', callback);
    };
  }, []);
  
  if (!names) return null;
  
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {names.map(name => <h2>{name}</h2>)}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```